# Mapping one of two classes that implements interface

Tags: java, hibernate

Class has property that can be one of two class-types, that's why I try to create interface that class-types implement

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User{  
@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long userID;
@Column(name="email")
private String email;
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
private Login login;
... getters/setters

@MappedSuperclass
public interface Login {
   User user = new User();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_logins_social")
@IdClass(UserLoginSocialID.class)
public class UserLoginSocial implements Login{      
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="uid")
    private User user;
...

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_logins_native")
public class UserLoginNative implements Login{
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="uid")
private User user;
...
```

So I can't use target entity because both classes can be used. Here is error stack: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: model.User.login, referenced property unknown: model.Login.user. Help me please

Comment: I think for this case You might need `Abstarct Class` cause you need Getters and setters for `user` object in your `Login` Interface

Answer (score 1):

Cannot map  or query on an inferface.

*@MappedSuperclass* should be able to use abstract class and class.

Please check: [wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Interfaces)http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Interfaces

```
@MappedSuperclass 
public abstract class User{  
@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long userID;

@Column(name="email")
private String email;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
private Login login;

// ... getters/setters

@Entity
@Table(name = "login")
public class Login{      
    @OneToOne
    private User user;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_logins_social")
@IdClass(UserLoginSocialID.class)
public class UserLoginSocial extends User{      
    //...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_logins_native")
public class UserLoginNative extends User{
  //...
}
```

Comment: what about make Login abstract class instead of interface and map it to POJO User. User has two ways of logging so it should be mapped to anyone of them, that's the idea